# Importance of do_fast_gettimeoffset( ) in linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

Was reading "Understanding Linux Kernel" book and in it says that, "number of microseconds is calculated by do_fast_gettimeoffset( )". Also it says that "to count the number of microseconds that have elapsed within the current second."

Couldnt understand what the author means by last sentence. Could anyone explain more on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to understand the linux kernel, you should be aware that that book has been outdated for a long time and that `do_fast_gettimeoffset` no longer exists.

`do_get_fast_time` returns the number of seconds, and is always fast.
`do_gettimeoffset` returns the number of microseconds since the start of the second, and might be slow.